# Can I file for federal tax returns for the year 2016 from India?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, income-tax-refund

I was working in US in 2016 while on a project but now I am in India. How do I file for tax returns from India for 2016?

I tried e filing through an agent last year but I provided my US postal address by mistake. The IRS says they sent me a letter to verify my identity. I did not get it as I was in India. As they did not hear from me they thought it was a fraudulent request and closed it.

Can I now file a new request with an Indian address? or is there a quicker way to have this fixed?

Comment: Mail?  Electronic?  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried e filing through an agent last year but I provided my US postal address by mistake. The IRS says they sent me a letter to verify my identity. I did not get it as I was in India. As they did not hear from me they thought it was a fraudulent request and closed it.

Comment: Can I now file a new request with an Indian address? or is there a quicker way to have this fixed?